# Enqueue kernel from kernel leads to a misunderstood build error

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, opencl

I need to launch a kernel from another kernel so I read the OpenCL specs and did exactly as mentioned but I got a **CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE**. Maybe my opencl version is less than 2.0 but I have downloaded OpenCL with CUDA so normally the version is upper than 2.0 right?

Here is my kernel code :

```
__kernel void funcB(__global int* a)
{
    //blabla
}

__kernel void funcA(__global int* a, const size_t n)
{
    //blabla

    void (^funcB)(void) = ^{funcB(a);};

    enqueue_kernel(get_default_queue(), CLK_ENQUEUE_FLAGS_WAIT_KERNEL, 
    ndrange_1d(n), funcB);
}
```

Do I also need to create a 'cl_kernel funcB' object in the host code ?? Or maybe import a header other than <CL/cl.h> ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What OpenCL device do you have (show `clinfo` output)? Nvidia only supports OpenCL C 1.2. For that feature you need either an Intel or AMD GPU (OpenCL 2.0-2.2). And you may need the OpenCL 2.0 headers.

Comment: i check my nvidia gpu spec and its supports opencl 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use OpenCL 2.0/2.1/2.2 features on OpenCL 1.1/1.2/3.0 devices.

Nvidia GPUs only support the OpenCL C 1.2 language standard (you can query this with `cl_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION>()`). Nvidia recently "upgraded" to OpenCL version 3.0, but this is just a new name for version 1.2. OpenCL 2.0/2.1/2.2 features are still not supported.

Comment: thanks, i checked the version like you said and yes its 1.2. So I think I will use CUDA.